# gprof collect no time data in program with lua 5.2 state

Tags: c++, lua, gprof

I'm trying measure overhead, we get by using lua script in C++ program. I decided to use gprof for that. I wrote simple program like:

1. Create lua state
2. Load lua libs
3. Do file with lua script

The problem is that gmon.out cointains no time data. It looks like that:

```
Flat profile:

Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
no time accumulated

%   cumulative   self              self     total           
time   seconds   seconds    calls  Ts/call  Ts/call  name    

%         the percentage of the total running time of the
time       program used by this function.

... //rest of file
```

I wonder if wrap this code in C functions or object functions (aka methods) makes any difference. I've also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18955839/gprof-not-displaying-time-i-e-it-is-displaying-0-0-time-even-if-it-is-taking-mo) topic but none of solutions works for me. Any idea?

Comment: Just to make sure: you have compiled all your programs modules, *including Lua*, with `-pg`, right?

Comment: Of course. I have similar program using 3rd party libraries and all works fine.